# How to configure both form authentication and azure authentication in same application (office 365)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Hello I have developed a Microsoft application using Microsoft Graph API in order to obtain planner data and store it in a database for now. On it's own the application works fine without any issue what so ever.

The next task for me is to integrate this separate application into the main company application. The main company's website uses form authentication. What is the best way to integrate this. Currently when I try to login to get authorized I am redirected to the form login not the Microsoft one

I have registered the application in the Microsoft application registration pool. I have also added the office 365 api

This is the token obtain code that i am using

```
    public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;


        tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(
          signedInUserID,
          HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase);
        //var cachedItems = tokenCache.ReadItems(appId); // see what's in the cache

        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            appId,
            redirectUri,
            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
            tokenCache);

        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' }));
            return result.Token;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (MsalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            throw new Exception(Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded);
        }
    }
```

This is the sign in method I am trying use when trying to directly log in

```
        // Signal OWIN to send an authorization request to Azure.
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
          new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
          OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by implementing the following code

```
    public ActionResult SignIn()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
        string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

        Uri authUri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL("https://graph.microsoft.com/", SettingsHelper.ClientId,
new Uri(redirectUri), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);

        // Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page
        return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        // Get the 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect
        string authCode = Request.Params["code"];

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthority);

        // The same url we specified in the auth code request
        string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

        // Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);

        try
        {
            // Get the token
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource);

            // Save the token in the session
            Session["access_token"] = authResult.AccessToken;

            return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme));
        }
        catch (AdalException ex)
        {
            return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving token: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

A link to the solution that helped tackle this was this. It's slightly old but still helped out massively 
https://www.vrdmn.com/2015/05/using-office-365-unified-api-in-aspnet.html